# Problems with aliases

Tags: mysql

Am generating sql query string from other stuff. I would like to have an alias and ORDER B for every selected item, mainly so that if two select parts come up with the same alias they will be coerced into unique column names in the result by appending -1, -2 etc rather than having multiple columns with the same name.

Simplified query:

```
SELECT '6' - `Amt`
FROM tbl
```

produces a result with column name '6' - `Amt` (as expected).

However, adding an alias:

```
SELECT '6' - `Amt` AS '6' - `Amt`
FROM tbl
```

produces an error.

Yet the same format in ORDER BY is fine:

```
SELECT '6' - `Amt`
FROM tbl
ORDER BY '6' - `Amt`
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-with-alias.html does talk about this.

The only thing I can think to do is strip the alias back to 6 - Amt but that is different to '6' - `Amt` which mysql creates if there is no alias.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why is this a problem?

Comment: " '6' - \`Amt\`" is not a valid alias, it is an expression. What do you mean by "two select parts", all queries you've shown only have one in any sense that phrase can be interpreted.

Comment: If you really really really want \` in your alias you can "escape" them by doubling them up, like \`6 - \`\`Amnt\`\`\`; but I would recommend against that unless there is a very very good reason for it.

Comment: @Uueerdo: Make that an answer and I'll accept it. I'd tried backslash, and I know about double apostrophe, but double backticks is the solution to this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really really really want ` in your alias you can "escape" them by doubling them up, like `6 - ``Amnt```

... but I would recommend against that unless there is a very very good reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT '6' - 'Amt' as `  '6' - ``Amt`` `
```

I am unsure with what you are trying to achieve, but this is possible by multiplying the ` in your query.

Im not sure why you would do this since this is bad practise, and I would advice not using this unless you must have to.

Comment: Yes, but that's not the same as '6' - \`Amt\` which mysql creates in the absence of an alias.

Comment: @Berniev that is exactly the same(aside from the case discrepancy); in the absence of an alias, mysql uses the expression that calculated the field as the alias.

Comment: Yeah, the default name of a column in your result set is the SQL that computed it *unless* you specify an alias.

Comment: @Uueerdo: No, it is not the same, note the single quotes around amt.